# How to make a particular constructor on a tempate type available only for a particular specialization in C++11?

Tags: c++11, templates, constructor

I have a C++11 template that can be specialized with an arbitrary type parameter.

```
template<class ElementType>
class Foo
```

How do I declare a constructor that appears for the compiler's consideration only when `ElementType` is e.g. `const uint8_t`?

That is, I have a bunch of constructors that are generic over any `ElementType`, but I also want to have constructors that are only considered when `ElementType` is specialized in a particular way. (Allowing those constructors to be selected for other types would be unsafe.)

So far `std::enable_if` examples that I've found have been conditional on the types of the arguments of the constructors.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class ElementType>
struct Foo
{
    template <typename T = ElementType> 
    Foo(typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, const uint8_t>{}>::type* = nullptr) {}

    template <typename T = ElementType> 
    Foo(typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, const uint8_t>{}>::type* = nullptr) {}     
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> a{}; // ok, calls first constructor
    Foo<const uint8_t> b{}; // ok, calls second constructor
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IIPTUBuEgv3lea1C)

Comment: When I try to use what you have as the only argument as the second argument to a constructor, clang tells me "error: no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if<false, void>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration"

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. You could try moving the `enable_if` to the templates parameter list as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the class into two classes. The derived class' purpose is to be able to specialize constructors for different types. E.g.:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

template<class ElementType>
struct Foo_
{
    Foo_() { std::printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
};

template<class ElementType>
struct Foo : Foo_<ElementType>
{
    using Foo_<ElementType>::Foo_; // Generic version.
};

template<>
struct Foo<uint8_t> : Foo_<uint8_t>
{
    Foo() { std::printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }  // Specialization for uint8_t.
};

int main(int ac, char**) {
    Foo<int8_t> a;
    Foo<uint8_t> b;
}
```

The benefit of using the derived class here compared to `enable_if` is that:

1. The class can be partially specialized.
2. Only one specialization of the class is chosen for particular template parameters, rather than a set of constructors. When adding specializations for new types the existing `enable_if` expressions may need to be changed to make them more restrictive to avoid function overload set resolution ambiguity.